# Asynchronous events

Tags: php, symfony, events, asynchronous

I'm trying to setup a background processing system for events. I'm using this tutorial : https://informulate.com/high-performance-through-asynch-operations-using-symfony-background-processing/

I followed all the steps but I have 2 issues :

- In the command, I don't know if the Event object given to the dispatcher is the Event entity or the Event default class. I think it should be the default class but if it is, how can I get the data from the Event entity in my Subscriber ?
- My subscriber doesn't seem to get the event.

Subscriber :

```
class QCModifiedSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, CorrectionReponseService $correctionReponse)
{
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->correctionReponse = $correctionReponse;
}

public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    // Liste des évènements écoutés et méthodes à appeler
    return array(
        'qc.modified' => 'calculStats'
    );
}

public function calculStats(Event $event)
{
    $data = $event->getData();
    $QC = $this->em->getRepository(QC::class)->find($data['qcId']);
    $this->correctionReponse->correctionReponsesOfQC($QC);
}
```

}

services.yml :

```
services:
    PACES\ColleBundle\EventListener\QCModifiedSubscriber:
        tags:
            - { name: 'kernel.event_subscriber'}
```

Command :

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    $dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();

    while (true) {
        $processId = rand(0, 999999999);
        # attempts to claim a single event, returns it if successful. may return multiple events.
        // note: $processId is some unique id to this process, helps prevent race conditions (see below)
        $events = $em->getRepository(Event::class)->claimEvent($processId);

        # no events to process, so break out of loop.
        if (count($events) === 0) {
            break;
        }

        # iterate over each event to be processed, typically just 1.
        foreach ($events as $eventEntity) {
            $output->write("Processing id: {$eventEntity->getId()}" . PHP_EOL);

            # create the event...
            $event = new \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event($eventEntity);

            try {
                # dispatch the event!
                $dispatcher->dispatch($eventEntity->getName(), $event);
                # if we made it here we were successful, mark as processed
                $eventEntity->setProcessed(1);

            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $eventEntity->setError((string)$e);
            }

            $em->persist($eventEntity);
            $em->flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Event entity is exactly the same as in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're within the Symfony framework and looking for a `kernel.event_subscriber`, you need to dispatch the event using Symfony's EventDispatcher rather than creating a new instance yourself.

Make sure your Command extends [ContainerAwareCommand](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html#getting-services-from-the-service-container):

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;

class MyCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
```

and change this line:

```
$dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
```

to this:

```
$dispatcher = $this->getContainer()->get('event_dispatcher');
```

To answer another question you had, the Event object given to the dispatcher is the Event class, not your Event entity.  What you have is also not going to work there ; if you look, the **[Event](http://api.symfony.com/3.3/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Event.html)** class does not take in any constructor arguments.  [Symfony's documentation states:](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-class)

> If you don't need to pass any additional data to the event listeners, you can also use the default Event class. In such case, you can document the event and its name in a generic StoreEvents class, similar to the KernelEvents class.

What you should do is create an event specific to your Event entity, like so:

```
namespace AppBundle\Event;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;
use AppBundle\Entity\Event as EventEntity;

class EntityEvent extends Event
{
    const NAME = 'entity.event';

    /**
     * @var EventEntity
     */
    protected $eventEntity;

    public function __construct(EventEntity $eventEntity)
    {
        $this->eventEntity = $eventEntity;
    }

    public function getEventEntity()
    {
        return $this->eventEntity;
    }
}
```

Now, you would create and dispatch your event like this:

```
use AppBundle\Event\EntityEvent;

// ...

$event = new EntityEvent($eventEntity);

// ...

$dispatcher->dispatch(EntityEvent::NAME, $event);
```

Then when you subscribe to the event you can get the Event entity via `$event->getEventEntity();` and operate on that event as you normally would.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. It's working perfectly now !

Comment: Glad you got it working!  The documentation tripped me up the first time as well, and I didn't realize that creating a new `EventDispatcher` from scratch worked as more of a standalone.